# Looped user input to text file. How to do it?

Tags: python-3.x

The point of this is that it asks for input (word/letters and number) and then saves the input to text file. Since it is a loop it should save all the "corret" inputs to file. My question is where do I put the last 3 lines or do I need something more?

```
def doit():                    # not important
    print("lalla")             # not important

def start():
    x = input("Write something (something)(nr)(C): ").split(' ')  # write a text and number. Using split to get two answers

    if 'C' in x:         # 'C' is for exit
        doit()
    else:
        try:              
            a = x[0]       # first string from input 
            b = x[1]         # second string from input 
            function(a,b)      # use them in next function
        except:
            start()             # if something goes wrong start again

def function(a,b):

    if not a.isalpha() or len(a) < 1:   # if a is not alpha or longer than 1
        start()                           # then back to input
    elif not b.isdigit() or int(b) < 1:    # if b is not number and bigger than 1
        start()    #then back to input
    else:
        print("Got it!")          # if everything is correct then says 'got it' and ask again till user inputs 'C'
        start()

start()
```

---

```
#f = open("database.txt", "w")  # open a text file for saving inputs
#f.write(INPUT)                 # write a line to text file
#f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the line

```
f = open("database.txt", "w")  # open a text file for saving inputs
```

before the global call to start (very last line).

You can write to the file at any point. Since you're not storing the input data, you could place your "write" line in the "else" branch of function.

Finally, the "close" call isn't really necessary and will be done anyway at the end of the program.

However, I suggest you refactor your code to use a while loop instead of recursion, like so:

```
f = open("database.txt", "w")
while True:
    try:
        a, b = input("...").split(' ')
        f.write(str(a) + ' ' + str(b) + '\n')

    except:
        #stop looping when there aren't two things in the line
        break

f.close()
```